# Прижать низ сайта к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Структура сайта следующая: есть общий блок (content), в котором расположены все элементы сайта и второй блок - footer, который должен прижиматься к низу сайта.

Блок Content имеет `position: absolute` для выравнивания по центру (горизонтально) - чтобы при уменьшении экрана он равномерно уходил за правую и левую его границы. Проблема в том, что при такой структуре блок Footer прижиматься к низу не хочет. Вот код:

HTML:

```
<div class = "a_wrapper">
    <div class = "a"></div>
</div>
<div class = "b">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.a_wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted #000000;
}
.a {
    height:800px;
}
.b {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k979ud5/

Comment: Вы хотите чтоб футер был на всю ширину страницы или на ширину контента?

Comment: Footer должен быть по ширине страницы, а Content - фиксированной ширины, поэтому поместить Footer  в Content не получится.

Comment: контент нельзя центрировать абсолютным позиционированием!!  Вы же не знаете ширину дисплея каждого юзера. Вам `margiin: 0 auto` ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: С центрированием контента, вроде, как раз проблем нет - выравнивается хорошо и на больших, и на маленьких экранах. Почему нельзя так центрировать? И если не так, то как тогда?

Comment: Потому, что надо знать основы верстки. Посмотрите [ссылку](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20div%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8) ...А спорить с вами только себе дороже.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, значит, все-таки, скриншот привести не смогли? А я скриншот приводил. К чему спорить, если можно без лишних слов показать, как отображается у вас? Вопрос в том, почему вы не можете этого сделать.

Comment: может так? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/n988da6m/

Comment: soledar10, нет, как раз нужно, чтобы нижний блок прокручивался вместе со страницей, а не был фиксированным.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Все то же самое, только `position: relative` в обоих случаях.

HTML:

```
<div class = "a_wrapper">
    <div class = "a"></div>
</div>
<div class = "b">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.a_wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #000000;
}
.a {
    height:800px;
}
.b {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0k979ud5/4/